# Windows Rearm count

Tags: windows, activation

Not sure if this belongs here because its not technically a 'programming' question, but i'm writing a small application that displays windows activation information by parsing the output of the slmgr.vbs script.

Now in my current system (which is activated), when I run the `slmgr.vbs -dlv` command it says `Remaining Windows rearm count: 3` Makes sense, since from what I've read you can use the -rearm command a total of 3 times. And I haven't run it on my computer ever.

But when I run `slmgr.vbs -dlv` on my virtual machine with Windows 7 Trial, and on my other computer I installed a Windows 7 trail on to test things, the output says `Remaining Windows rearm count: 4`

Can someone explain why it says I can use the -rearm command 4 times?

Comment: A simple explanation would be that you haven't activated that trial install yet.  And yes, it is off topic here.  Post these kind of questions to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Trial Windows 7 the rearm count is set to 4 and once the trail converts to full version the same rearm count is set to 3 default. Or when you install full version of Windows the rearm count is set 3 by default.

Comment: So if I continue on the trial, I can actually rearm 4 times for a total of 150 days?

Comment: It does not work that way. Actually after 30 days of eval period some other factors comes in existence. I can not comment those factors however i just answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Windows Script Host
>
> Software licensing service version: 6.1.7601.17514
>
> Name: Windows(R) 7, Ultimate edition
>
> Description: Windows Operating System - Windows(R) 7, OEM_SLP channel
>
> Activation ID: xxxx
>
> Application ID: nun.ya
>
> Extended PID: Nun.ya
>
> Installation ID: Nun.ya
>
> Partial Product Key: Nun.ya
>
> License Status: Initial grace period
>
> Time remaining: 7860 minute(s) (5 day(s))
>
> **Remaining Windows rearm count: 5**
>
> Trusted time: 11/6/2012 11:47:46 AM

---

I don't know where you people get  your info, but as you can see, the rearm count can be greater than 3 or even 4..